# How should I tag Pipeline Number under a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have create a new Pipeline "test". Under this Pipeline I have three jobs.

Job No#-

A- Build
B- Test
C- Publish

If I "Run" pipeline, all the three jobs get executed one after the other.

My Issue- How should I get Job A's Build No# as my Tag in Job C.(To track).

[image]

Error Logs--

```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe tag -l 9 # timeout=10
ERROR: Step ‘Git Publisher’ failed: Tag 9 already exists and Create Tag is specified, so failing.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Parameterized Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) to accomplish that.
Basically, what you want to do is pass the build number of job `A` from job `A` down to job `C` as a parameter, as described in the above schema :

[image]

To do that, you have to :

- Pass a parameter `JOB_A_BUILD_NUMBER` from job `A` to `B` using "trigger parameterized build" in job `A`.
- Pass a parameter `JOB_A_BUILD_NUMBER` from job `B` to `C` using "trigger parameterized build" in job `B`.
- Use this parameter as a variable in your Git publisher using `$JOB_A_BUILD_NUMBER`.

To configure a parameterized job, you can just do that :

[image]

Comment: I am unable to get the Build number from Job A to Job C. Attached picture.

Comment: I have edited my post with a capture showing how to add the `BUILD_NUMBER` parameter